# The ArrayList set and get is putting my code out of bounds

Tags: java

I am trying to get my new List I have created to go through the for loop as well as the int random I have to set the index of I to be a random integer each time. I input a size and it is supposed to take the question bank and randomize the question. when I had an array for my code it worked perfectly fine but after changing it to object list it will not work now. It is giving me the error "IndexOutOfBoundsExeption". I am not sure if I am doing this correctly.

## Bank Code

```
    public class TestBank {
        private List<Question> bank;

    public List<Question> randomize(int amountQuestions, int size) {
        int usedQuestions[] = new int[amountQuestions]; // usedQuestions[] is amount of Q's
        ArrayList<Question> bank = new ArrayList<Question>(size); // bank is new ObjectiveQuestion of size entered
        System.out.println(bank);
        for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) { // for loop through size entered
            usedQuestions[i] = 1; // used question in idex is equal to 1
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) { // for loop through size entered
            int random = (int) Math.round(Math.random() * (amountQuestions - 1)); 
            System.out.println(random);
            while(usedQuestions[random] == -1) { 
                random = (int) Math.round(Math.random() * (amountQuestions - 1));
            }
            bank.set(i, bank.get(random)); 
            usedQuestions[random] = -1; 
        }
        return bank; 
    }
```

Comment: When posting here, you should strip down your code to bare minimum needed to demonstrate your issue/problem.

Comment: Ok, I have tried doing that

Comment: Using `List<Object>` is not a good idea.  You should be using `List<Question>`.

Comment: Should I use this throughout the entire code?

Comment: @AceHigh Please read [mre].  If your question is about arraylists, then that's all that should be in the code.  It should just have an arraylist and call the get/set method.  It really shouldn't be more than about 5 lines.

Comment: Alright, done :)

Comment: Not really, the code won't compile. It's also not clear what `amountOfQuestions` and `usedQuestions` variables contain, together with the `random` variable they might be the source of error.

Comment: I have a main with question types so amountOfQuestions could be anything in my case 20 and the usedQuestions is supposed to be what you enter

Comment: int amountQuestions = bank.size();

Comment: When I was using an Array, I did bank[i] = bank[random] and this did what I wanted to do for an Array as far as setting each index to the random number